# Are complex numbers the only field that leads to the equivalence of analyticity and differentiability?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

One of the most beloved properties of complex numbers is that doing analysis on complex functions leads to the fact that every continuously differentiable complex function is analytic (and if it is $C^1$ it is automatically $C^{\infty}$) which is naturally something very comfortable to have. I was wondering what made the complex numbers so special; certainly, the fact that they constitute a field sets them apart from, for example, $\mathbb{R}^2$, as a setting for doing analysis on it. But are they unique in that regard? 
 A central fact about analysis on complex functions seems to be that Green's Theorem leads to Cauchy's Theorem, and then the topology of complex numbers leads to Cauchy's integral formula, from whence the equivalence of continuous differentiability and analiticity can be obtained. So maybe they are unique, because for other fields where a similar concept of differentiation this line of reasoning would not hold; but there might be other routes. 
 So my question is as follows: let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, and, for a function from $\mathbb{F}$ to $\mathbb{F}$, $g$, let a similar notion for differentiation be established (ie $g$ is differentiable on $a \in \mathbb{F} $ if $g(a+h)-g(a)=f_a\cdot h+o(h)$, for $h \in \mathbb{F}, $and $f_a$ is the derivative). Suppose that every continuously differentiable function in an open set (in some topology one might bestow onto $\mathbb{F}$) is analytic in that open set. Does that force $\mathbb{F}$  to be the complex numbers, with the Euclidean topology? Or might there be other fields, with differentent topologies, which have this property?

**EDIT:**
 I would like to better frame the question following the sugestions in the comments. Firstly, let $\mathbb{F}$ be a topological field such that the operations are continuous given some arbitrary topology. Further, let $g: \mathbb{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ be a differentiable function in an open set $U$ in the following sense: $$\forall a \in U, \exists g_a \in \mathbb{F} \, \text{s.t} \hspace{2mm}g(a+h)-g(a)=g_a \cdot h+o(h)$$
for some $h \in \mathbb{F}$ and where $o(h)$ is the standard little oh definition. 
 Suppose we have that $g$ differentiable in some open set $U$ $\iff$ $g$ is analytic in $U$. Does this restrict the topology and the algebra of $\mathbb{F}$ enough to conclude that it should be $\mathbb{C}$ with the euclidean topology? If not, up to where could we constrain them, in view of maybe arriving at some necessary or even sufficient conditions for a topological field to have that property?

Comment: A function which is complex differentiable is already analytic, you do not need to assume the derivative is continuous. Indeed you don't need Green's theorem to develop the theory -- you can develop the theory from "Cauchy's theorem for a triangle" etc. never needing more than complex differentiability in order to establish the integral formula. (This is due to Goursat I believe). It seems difficult to imagine where other examples could come from, because there are so few normed division algebras over $\mathbb R$, and the context is very different if you start with, e.g. a p-adic field.

Comment: @krm2233 The condition of holomorphy on an open set can be squeezed to $f$ having partial derivatives that satisfy Cauchy-Riemann. This is Looman-Menchoff theorem, an exposition of which is in chapter 1 of *Complex Analysis in One Variable*, by R. Narasimhan.

Comment: @krm2233 I only added that because most of the time that (CR+ C1) is the sufficient condition for complex differentiability. But I suppose if there's a simpler way one may drop the C1 requirement. Nonetheless, what I'm trying to get at in this post is precisely if one may deduce the algebraic and topological properties of the field given that diff equals analiticity

Comment: Note that when you are talk about $o(h)$, you are already assuming that $\Bbb F$ has a topology. And possibly your formulation may assume that addition and multiplication are continuous under that topology (I haven't verified that, but life would be considerably more difficult if either operation were discontinuous).

Comment: @PaulSinclair that surely would make things easier and I don't think one loses a lot of generality if we further impose that. Should I make an edit?

Comment: Yes. Introduce $\Bbb F$ as a topological field, instead of an arbitrary field.

Comment: I suppose you want to exclude finite fields with the discrete topology.

Comment: @LukasHeger why? Would that be problematic for the differentiability?

Comment: No, I just thought it is too "trivial" to be a satisfying answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that one can develop the basic theory of complex analytic functions without using Cauchy's theorems at all. Essentially you need a notion of winding number (i.e. a topological index map) from which you can establish results like Rouche's theorem (and an open mapping theorem presumably). This seems to go back to a monograph by Whyburn called "Topological analysis" which I can't get hold of, but there are various papers based on it which deduce that a complex differentiable function must be analytic (amongst other things).

Apart from being intriguing in its own right (given how accustomed one is to deducing these things from Cauchy's Integral formula) it seems that this approach has been used more recently by Peterzil and Starchenko to study "expansions of algebraically closed fields in $o$-minimal structures". I'm afraid my knowledge of $o$-minimal structures is extremely slight (I get by by thinking about semi-algebraic sets basically) but this theory takes a real-closed subfield $R$ of an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero as input. Now a real-closed field is one which obeys the same first-order theory as the real numbers, and its algebraic closure is thus $R[\sqrt{-1}]=K$ say, but $R$ may still be quite different from $\mathbb R$ (it can be non-Archimedean for example). The $o$-minimal structure of $R$ then gives a notion of $definable$ functions from $K$ to itself, and the definable functions from $K$ to itself which are differentiable turn out to be analytic.

Now the appearance of an $o$-minimal structure is obviously something that wasn't "allowed" in the original question posed, but it seems at least close enough in spirit to what was asked, and also quite surprising, that I thought it was worth pointing out!

Comment: Then this seems to be a negative answer to my question, right? That's extremely curious. I'll have to research about it

Comment: As I said at the end of my post, I'm not sure this theory falls properly within the parameters your question set, but it does mean that it appears you can frame very similar questions where analyticity follows from differentiability for a whole family of examples. I guess that means that as an answer it is a qualified "no"! It does seem interesting that these $o$-minimal theories use a real-closed field and its algebraic closure, rather than just an algebraically closed field $K$, because it means one views $K$ as a "plane" in something of the same way as we view $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I agree. It's very curious that algebraic closure plays a role, and the interplay between it and o-minimality seems rather cryptic. I've accepted your answer, thanks for the insight!

Comment: I learned some cool things thinking about this, so thanks for posing the question!